# Search for Custom Field with Custom Post Types

Tags: wordpress, search, custom-post-type, custom-fields

There are tutorials that explain how to limit a search to a specific category.

My question is, is there a way to configure wordpress' search to, within a custom post type, search for a custom field value.

So for example, if I search for "hello", the results would come up with posts that have a certain custom field equal to "hello". The certain post would also be a certain custom post type.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

To filter search by custom post type use:

```
<?php query_posts($query_string . '&post_type=custom-post-type-name' ); ?>
```

before the loop.. then within the loop add a condition similar to this

```
<?php if ($meta_data[ 'meta-name' ] == 'hello') {
    //do something
} ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think here is what you are looking for:

key is the custom field.
value is the value you are looking for
and compare is the operator you want to use.
you can also use LIKE if you want.

```
// WP_Query arguments
$args = array (
    'post_type'              => 'vendors',
    'post_status'            => 'published',
    'meta_query'             => array(
        array(
            'key'       => 'state',
            'value'     => 'Misissipi',
            'compare'   => '=',
        ),
    ),
);

// The Query
$query = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        $query->the_post();
        // do something
    }
} else {
    // no posts found
}

// Restore original Post Data
wp_reset_postdata();
```